# Synchronize sending to a spring integration channel with spring aspect transaction

Tags: transactions, spring-integration, channel, aspect

I have some spring aspect. The aspects have a sequential order. In the last aspect, I send a message to a spring integration channel. I need that send to be in transactional which it syncs with all my aspects, it means when the transaction of aspects commit, then message send to the channel.

I read about ChainedTransactionManager class. but I don't understand how can I get aspects transactions and pass to this object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you can try to obtain from the `ChainedTransactionManager`, but for me it more sounds like a `TransactionSynchronization`. You register an instance of this with the `TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization()` and in its `afterCommit()` implementaiton you send your message to the channel.

There is no reason to wrap a send to the channel if channel is not a transactional resource.